# DMS replication to Kinesis omit certain fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-migration, aws-dms, amazon-kinesis

We have a use case where we have enabled a AWS DMS replication task which streams changes to our Aurora Postgres cluster to a Kinesis Data stream. The replication task is working as expected but the data that its sending to Kinesis Data Stream as json contains fields like `metadata` that we don't care about and would ideally like to omit them. Is there a way to do this without triggering a Lambda on KDS to remove the unwanted fields from the json?

I was looking at using table mappings config of the DMS task when KDS is the target, documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kinesis.html. The docs don't mention anything of this sort. Maybe I am missing something.

The current table mapping for my usecase is as follows -

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "1",
            "rule-action": "include",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "public",
                "table-name": "%"
            }
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "object-mapping",
            "rule-id": "2",
            "rule-name": "DefaultMapToKinesis",
            "rule-action": "map-record-to-record",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "public",
                "table-name": "testing"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The table testing only has two columns namely `id` and `value` of type `varchar` and `decimal` respectively.

The result I am getting in KDS is as follows -

```
{
    "data": {
        "id":   "5",
        "value":    1111.22
    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp":    "2022-08-23T09:32:34.222745Z",
        "record-type":  "data",
        "operation":    "insert",
        "partition-key-type":   "schema-table",
        "schema-name":  "public",
        "table-name":   "testing",
        "transaction-id":   145524
    }
}
```

As seen above we are only interested in the `data` key of the json.

Is there any way in DMS config or KDS to filter on the data portion of the json sent by DMS without involving any new infra like Lambda?